# AD Web Services fail to respond to Get-ADGroupMember request periodically

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have a client, where the simple line

```
Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "SomeGroupName"
```

Return an error "The server was unable to process the request due to internal error" periodically. Sometimes I do receive an answer.
It's a group of about 1000 members.
What can be the problem and where should I be looking?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you searched for your specific error message?

Comment: Do you perhaps have group names that have characters in there that need to be escaped? (see https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5312.active-directory-characters-to-escape.aspx). If that is the case, try `Get-ADGroupMember -Identity ("SomeGroupName" -creplace '\\(?![0-9A-Fa-f]{2})|[,+"<>;=/]|^[ #]| $', '\$&')`

Comment: @Bill_Stewart the full error message continues as: For more information about the  error, either turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from the <serviceDebug> configuration behavior) on the server in order to send the exception information back to the client, or turn on tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework 3.0.SDK documentation and inspect the server trace logs.

Comment: @Theo It happens everytime on different group, and, as I can see, does not come from unescaped characters. Thanks anyway, I learned something new!

Comment: can you give us an example of a group that gives the error and can you check if none of the members of that failing group maybe have characters that need escaping?